# How use a special attribute inside an include in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize, i have an special attribute that i created using sequelize.fn("MIN", sequelize.col("column")), and i want to use this inside an include, like that:

```
    const proposal = await ProposalHistory.findAll({
            attributes: [
                sequelize.fn("MIN", sequelize.col("createDate")), <- THIS IS THE SPECIAL ATTRIBUTE
                "fk_id_proposal",
            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: Proposal,
                    as: "proposal",
                    attributes: [
                        "status",
                        [
                            Sequelize.literal(
                                `sum(case when || HERE I WANT TO USE || >= '${MIN.createDate}')`
                            ),
                            "Implanted",
                        ],
            ]
```

Is this possible? How can i do this?